# I need to check if any <td> in a html table is empty/null as in after the page loads it only returns <td></td> and change it to <td><p>$0</p></td>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

example of the table

```
        <table class="tg">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="tg-0lax" id="blank-spaces"></th>
                    <th class="titles" id="this">????</th>
                    <th class="titles">???<br></th>
                    <th class="titles">???</th>
                    <th class="titles">???</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                   <td></td>
                   <td>not empty do nothing</td>
                   <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        <table>
```

Now the way this is really written, data will be pushed into each td from an API, some times that API is down, and I would like to use jquery to check if a td has anything displaying in it and if it doesnt I want there to be a string with an error message in the td. This is the jquery im trying currently

```
var empty = $("td").trim().filter(function () { return this.value.trim() === null })
empty.addClass("errorDefault");

if ($("td").hasClass("errorDefault")) {
    this.val("$0");
    this.text("$0");
    this.html("<p>There was an error getting data</p>");
}
```

Comment: You need to iterate over all the cells, like `$("td").each(...)` (also please don't tag your question with unrelated tags)

Comment: TDs don't normally have a `value` attribute. Use innerHTML or textContent instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is no .trim() in jQuery
- string trim() is not going to return null.
- table cells do not have value
- $("td").hasClass("errorDefault") only looks at first element

```js
$("tbody td")
  .filter((_, td) => !td.textContent.trim().length)
  .addClass("errorDefault")
  .text("$0");
```

```css
.errorDefault {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-0lax" id="blank-spaces"></th>
      <th class="titles" id="this">????</th>
      <th class="titles">???<br></th>
      <th class="titles">???</th>
      <th class="titles">???</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>not empty do nothing</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

If it is truly empty, CSS can do it.

```css
tbody td:empty{
  background: red;
}

tbody td:empty:after {
  content: "$0";
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-0lax" id="blank-spaces"></th>
      <th class="titles" id="this">????</th>
      <th class="titles">???<br></th>
      <th class="titles">???</th>
      <th class="titles">???</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>not empty do nothing</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for your help with this, the jquery didnt end up working for me probably because of information that I cant provide right now, but the css method did what I needed, thanks been stuck on this for a a few days!